# use if function to pull a date from a column if it is there or another if it is missing in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an excel spreadsheet used for tracking projects and need to add some functionality for different types of projects and timeline constraints. Below is an example of the 2 conditions I need to meet.
Received- When project is received on site.

Construction completion- this is one type of project that requires 3-4 weeks to complete. this date will usually be entered manually, but may be set to start automatically at 4 weeks after Received date. If if does not require construction it is set to n.a.

Midi Expected-
This is where I need a statement that reads `if there is a date in "Construction Completion" add 7, if there is not then use the date in received and add 7`.

QC Completion-
This is simply `Midi Expected + 7`

| Received | Construction Completion | Midi Expected | QC Completion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/20/2021 | n.a. | 5/7/2021 | 5/14/2021 |
| 5/20/2021 | 6/10/2021 | 6/17/2021 | 6/24/2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Received" is at A1, put this in C2 :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2)=TRUE,B2+7,A2+7)
```

Then format the cell as Date. Done.

To make it more robust, use :

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(B2)=TRUE,B2+7,A2+7))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `CELL` function. Try-

```
=IF(CELL("format",B2)="D1",B2+7,A2+7)
```

[image]